# C++ Initialize function pointer in constructor

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I have a function pointer to a member function in class. How do I initialize this function pointer since I get a warning on compilation every time. Here is the code:

```
//Node.h
class Node{
    bool (Node::*strategyPointer)(const unsigned int&);
    Node();
};

//Node.cpp
Node::Node(){

    //How do I initialize my pointer here?
}
```

thanks

Comment: How are you doing the initialisation currently, and what warnings do you get?

Comment: I am not doing any initialization currently. I am using them in a member function as follows: strategyPointer=&Node::peeringStrategyOpen; I get the error: Member strategyPointer was not initialized in this constructor.

Comment: That doesn't sound like an error in the assignment to me, please show the (minimal) complete code.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't have any methods it *could* legally point to, so let's add some:

```
class Node{
    bool (Node::*strategyPointer)(const unsigned int&);

    bool firstStrategy(const unsigned int&)  { return true;  }
    bool secondStrategy(const unsigned int&) { return false; }

public:
    Node();
};
```

Now we have a valid value to initialize it with, just use:

```
Node::Node() : strategyPointer(&Node::firstStrategy) {}
```

Comment: When I use  strategyPointer(&Node::firstStrategy) {} in the constructor, it gives me a syntax error. Is that syntax right?

Comment: Yes. Show the _minimal complete code_ (including the declaration of your `firstStrategy` or whatever method) _and the error_ if you want us to help with them.

Comment: Awesome. If you think it might help anyone else in the future, you could edit your question to say what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't initialize it to a particular function, better to assign it that function when you actually need it.  Rather just initialize it to null:

```
Node::Node() : strategyPointer(nullptr)
{
}
```

This also lets you easily test whether `strategyPointer` has been used, by `if (strategyPointer!=nullptr)` or just `if (strategyPointer)`.

Lastly, doing it this way allows you the option of having `Node` be an (abstract) base class which does not in fact possess any member functions of the right signature.